# Error LNK2019 y LNK 1120 visual c++ 2012 usando SDL

Tags: c++

Estoy empezando a usar SLD y SDL_image he buscado información del error y en la mayoria de los casos es por una mala configuracion con el vinculador en visual studio 2012, sin embargo he utilizado las soluciones mostradas, pero no afectan. les presento el codigo los errores que salen al momento de compilar son :

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: __thiscall Game::Game(void)" (??0Game@@QAE@XZ) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _SDL_main   C:\Users\Miguel G. Pelagio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SDL_game\SDL_game\main.obj SDL_game

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 externos sin resolver  C:\Users\Miguel G. Pelagio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SDL_game\Debug\SDL_game.lib    SDL_game
```

Si alguien pasó por una situación similar o entiende el por qué del problema me pueda ayudar para seguir adelante con mi estudio en SDL.

main.ccp

```
#include<SDL.h>
#include "Game.h"
#include <Windows.h>

//our Game object
Game* g_game=0;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   AllocConsole ();
   g_game= new Game();
   g_game->init ("Chapter 2",100,100,640,480,false);

   while(g_game->running ())
   {
    g_game->handleEvents();
    g_game->update ();
    g_game->render();
   }
  g_game->clean ();
  return 0;
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef _Game_
#define _Game_
#include "SDL.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"

class Game
{

 public:
   Game();
   ~Game();
   //simply the Running variable to true  
 bool init(const char* title,int xpos,int ypos,int width ,int height,bool fullscreen);
  void render();
  void update();
  void handleEvents();
  void clean();

// a function to acces the private running variable 
bool running(){return m_bRunning;}
private:
  SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
  SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer; 

int m_currentFrame;
TextureManager m_textureManager;
bool m_bRunning;
};
#endif/*define(_Game_)*/
```

Game.ccp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL_image.h>
using namespace std;

bool Game::init(const char* title,int xpos,int ypos,int width ,int height,bool fullscreen)
{
   //attempt to initialize SDL
   if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING )==0)
   {
      int flags=0;
        if(fullscreen )
        {
            flags=SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN ;
        }

    std::cout<<"SDL init success\n"<<endl;
    //init the window 
    m_pWindow=SDL_CreateWindow (title,xpos,ypos,width,height,flags);
    //Window init success
    if(m_pWindow !=0)
    {
        std::cout <<"window creation success\n"<<std::endl;
        m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer (m_pWindow ,-1,0);
        if(m_pRenderer !=0)//Render init success
        {
            std::cout<<"renderer creation success\n";
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (m_pRenderer, 255,0,0,255);
            m_textureManager.load("C:/Users/Miguel G. Pelagio/Pictures/pruebas SDL/animate-alpha.png","animate",m_pRenderer);

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"renderer init fail\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Window init fail\n";
    }
}
else 
{
    std::cout<<"SDL init fail\n";
} 

std::cout<<"init success\n";
m_bRunning =true;//everything initied successfully, start the main loop
    return true;
}
void Game::render()
{
   SDL_RenderClear (m_pRenderer );//clear the renderer to draw color
     m_textureManager.draw("animate",0,0,128,82,m_pRenderer,SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    m_textureManager.drawFrame("animate",100,100,128,82,1,m_currentFrame,m_pRenderer,SDL_FLIP_NONE);
  SDL_RenderPresent (m_pRenderer );

 }

 void Game::handleEvents ()
 {
   SDL_Event event;
    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
     switch (event.type)
      {
         case SDL_QUIT :
           m_bRunning =false;
           break;
         default:
            break;
       }
      }
     }
 void Game::update()
 {
  m_currentFrame= int((SDL_GetTicks()/100)%6);
 }
void Game::clean ()
{
  std::cout<<"Cleaning game\n";
  SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow) ;
  SDL_DestroyRenderer (m_pRenderer);
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

TextureManager.h

```
#ifndef _Game1_
#define _Game1_
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

class TextureManager
{

  public:
  bool load(std::string fileName,std::string id,SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
  void draw(std::string id,int x,int y,int width,int height,SDL_Renderer*   pRenderer,SDL_RendererFlip flip);
  void drawFrame(std::string id,int x,int y,int width,int heigh,int concurrentRow,int concurrentFrame,SDL_Renderer* pRenderer,SDL_RendererFlip flip);

  private:

   std::map<std::string,SDL_Texture*> m_textureMap;
};
#endif/*define(_Game_)*/
```

TextureManager.ccp

```
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL_image.h>
using namespace std;

bool TextureManager::load(std::string fileName,std::string id,SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
   SDL_Surface* pTempSurface=IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());
   if(pTempSurface==0)
   {
      return false;
   }

   SDL_Texture* pTexture=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer,pTempSurface);
   SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);

   //everything went ok, add the texture to our map
   if(pTexture!=0)
   {
      m_textureMap[id]=pTexture;
      return true;
   }
   //reaching here means somthing went wrong
   return false; 
}

void TextureManager::draw(std::string id,int x,int y,int width,int  height,SDL_Renderer* pRenderer,SDL_RendererFlip flip=SDL_FLIP_NONE)
{
  SDL_Rect srcRect;
  SDL_Rect destRect;

  srcRect.x=0;
  srcRect.y=0;
  srcRect.w=destRect.w=width;
  srcRect.h=destRect.h=height;
  destRect.x=x;
  destRect.y=y;
  SDL_RenderCopyEx(pRenderer,m_textureMap[id],&srcRect,&destRect,0,0,flip);
}

void TextureManager::drawFrame(std::string id,int x,int y,int width,int  heigh,int concurrentRow,int concurrentFrame,SDL_Renderer*  pRenderer,SDL_RendererFlip flip=SDL_FLIP_NONE)
{
  SDL_Rect srcRect;
  SDL_Rect destRect;
  srcRect.x=width*concurrentFrame;
  srcRect.y=heigh*(concurrentRow-1);
  srcRect.w=destRect.w=width;
  srcRect.h=destRect.h=heigh;
  destRect.x=x;
  destRect.y=y;

     SDL_RenderCopyEx(pRenderer,m_textureMap[id],&srcRect,&destRect,0,0,flip);
}
```

Comment: "*error símbolo externo sin resolver *" es porque el compilador no encuentra el cuerpo de una función (`Game::Game`). Asegúrate de incluir/compilar todos los `*.cpp`.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Te recomiendo que te pases por el [tour] para que tengas unas nociones sobre cómo funciona este portal. Lo recomendable es que proporciones un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que reproduzca el error. Si pones un ejemplo de 500 líneas no vas a atraer demasiada atención

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error   1   error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: __thiscall Game::Game(void)" (??0Game@@QAE@XZ) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _SDL_main   C:\Users\Miguel G. Pelagio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SDL_game\SDL_game\main.obj SDL_game

Este error se produce porque te falta la implementación del constructor por defecto. Revisa el cpp que has publicado en tu pregunta y verás que no se encuentra dicha implementación.

> Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 externos sin resolver  C:\Users\Miguel G. Pelagio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SDL_game\Debug\SDL_game.lib    SDL_game

Este error te da debido seguramente a que el error anterior impide que puedas generar la librería `SDL_game.lib` y, en consecuencia, el programa no puede montarse.

Comment: si gracias olvide que puse explisito el constructor pense que era por configuracion, te agradezco tu ayuda saludos

Comment: @miguelgarcia si el constructor no va a tener código quizás debieras borrar la declaración y dejar que sea el compilador el que cree una versión por defecto.